# Why SocketIo Client c# using EIO=4 still can't connect to Socket Server v4x

Tags: c#, socket.io, real-time

i have some problem with socket io client , thats why i use EIO = 4 still not able to connect Socket server v4x . Or the problem is not with the version . Hope everyone can help me. Thank you so much!

```
var options = new SocketIOOptions() { Reconnection = true, ReconnectionDelay = 250, EIO = 4};
    socket = new SocketIO(uri, options);
    socket.JsonSerializer = new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer(socket.Options.EIO);
  

    socket.ConnectAsync(); // OnConnected = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried update new version SocketIoClient and its working ! =)